# Moto G back up without booting

Tags: backup, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G first generation that is stuck on the M boot screen.  I have tried going to recovery and wiping cache but the cache wipe does not complete even after hours (it stays on wiping/formatting cache).  Is there a way to back up what's on the phone without it booting (so I can then try the factory reset)?  Thanks!

Comment: I assume the device bootloader has not been unlocked, right?

Comment: Right, the bootloader has not been unlocked.